# Jupyter Notebook validation failed

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I open a file in jupyter notebook, I get this error.

[image]

```
Notebook validation failed: {'model_id': '47c3f67b01814c2baeeca6efa0a79e2d', 'version_major': 2, 'version_minor': 0} is not valid under any of the given schemas:
{
 "model_id": "47c3f67b01814c2baeeca6efa0a79e2d",
 "version_major": 2,
 "version_minor": 0
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and this solution works like a charm:

https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/issues/161

*TLDR:* open your file on a text editor and replace "nbformat_minor": 1 with "nbformat_minor": 4

Comment: The link no longer exists and is not in the wayback machine.

Comment: For some reason, the link returned to normal...

Comment: The link once more had disappear. Maybe now it will forever... I will edit to include a link from Github instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you activated conda environment correctly. In my case conda environment was not correctly activated so that was the problem. As I activated correctly everything worked normal.

Answer (score 0):

I think different issues cause the error, one of them is:

The bug happens because the code blocks from Colab are missing "outputs':[] and "execution_count":null.

```
{
    "cell_type": "code",
    "metadata": {
     "id": "e2769b9e0005"
   },
    "source": [
      "!pip install git+https://github.com/google/starthinker\n"
    ]
  },
```

To fix add the missing fields to the colab source for any code block only not markdown:

```
{
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": null,
    "outputs": [],
    "metadata": {
      "id": "e2769b9e0005"
    },
    "source": [
      "!pip install git+https://github.com/google/starthinker\n"
    ]
 },
```